# On the Qiskit Txtbk page for TSP, how does the initial phase matrix work?

Tags: qiskit, linear-algebra, phase-kickback

I am looking over the TSP on Qiskit's Textbook, link below:
https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-paper-implementations/tsp.html#Building-the-Components-
In the general strategy part of the documentation, they convert the matrices U1 -> U4 to Uj, and in this step they introduce four variables, a through d, that when manipulated, can, as I understand, lead back to the original matrices U1-4. The text is in the picture below:
[image]

Should I be interpretting this less literally, or is the task to keep going finding these values a through d. I think I just got lost around here, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!